# Parse XML response String with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

In my application, I am getting an XML response from my server while calling webservice. The the response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"rows":[{"noteId" : "1", "procedure" : "D0140", "teeth": "", "encounterno": "123456" , "WorkflowCode": "Submitted", "datecreated": "10/27/2011", "surf": "", "description": "Limited Oral Evaluation-Problem Focused","status": "Existing","prefdate": "10/27/2011 05:06" }, {"noteId" : "2", "procedure" : "D0140", "teeth": "", "encounterno": "123456" , "WorkflowCode": "Submitted", "datecreated": "11/07/2011", "surf": "", "description": "Limited Oral Evaluation-Problem Focused","status": "Completed","prefdate": "01/01/2011 05:08" },{"noteId" : "3", "procedure" : "D0140", "teeth": "", "encounterno": "123456" , "WorkflowCode": "Submitted", "datecreated": "04/01/2011", "surf": "", "description": "Limited Oral Evaluation-Problem Focused","status": "Completed","prefdate": "02/01/2011 05:08" },{"noteId" : "4", "procedure" : "D0140", "teeth": "", "encounterno": "123456" , "WorkflowCode": "Submitted", "datecreated": "01/10/2011", "surf": "", "description": "Limited Oral Evaluation-Problem Focused","status": "Completed","prefdate": "01/01/2011 05:08" },{"noteId" : "5", "procedure" : "D0140", "teeth": "", "encounterno": "123456" , "WorkflowCode": "Submitted", "datecreated": "01/27/2011", "surf": "", "description": "Limited Oral Evaluation-Problem Focused","status": "Completed","prefdate": "10/05/2011 05:08" }]}</string>
```

I want to parse this string using jQuery Mobile and content will be displayed in jQuery Mobile list view.

How can I parse this response?

Comment: Why do you put a JSON string that you would like to parse in JS into an XML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Once you've the parsed object you can create a list (ul or ol).

Then call

```
$(listItem).listview('refresh')
```

each time you add a list item element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when following above link example i am not able to get the value. Because in my xml string having json object. So it is not accepted.Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: @nari sorry you're right. Can you use the substring searching for the first occurence of { ?
Not elegant but should work.